# When does GHCI not deduce the required context?

Tags: haskell

Why does GHCI add constraint for the required context here:

```
> let f = fmap show

> :t f
f :: (Functor f, Show a) => f a -> f String
```

But not here?

```
> :t over
over :: Lens s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> t

> :t _all'
_all' :: (Applicative f, Eq a) => a -> (a -> f a) -> [a] -> f [a]

> :t over (_all' 2)

<interactive>:1:7: error:
    • Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘_all'’
```

Is there any major difference between these two cases?

Comment: Note that isn't the type of `over` as defined by the [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:over) library. That being said, your version doesn't work because `Lens` is `forall f . Functor f => ..` and `_all' 2 :: forall f . Applicative f => ..`; in other words, `over` is demanding a function which works for any `Functor`, but you've provided one which only works for `Applicative` (which is a stronger constraint, in that `Functor` doesn't imply `Applicative`).

Comment: @user2407038 that's an answer.

Comment: Having explicit signatures available on the right hand expressions only is sufficient to engage the type checker before inferencer can deduce the appropriate constraint on the left hand side. I'm posting this as comment because I don't understand whether that's necessary or incidental.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that isn't the type of `over` as defined by the lens library. That being said, your version doesn't work because `Lens` is
>
> ```
> type Lens = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> _all' 2 :: forall f. Applicative f => ..
> ```
>
> In other words, `over` is demanding a function which works for any `Functor`, but you've provided one which only works for `Applicative` (which is a stronger constraint, in that `Functor` doesn't imply `Applicative`).

Comment by @user2407038.

As alluded to in the comment, you can fix your problem by fixing the type signature for `over`. It should either be the complicated fancy thing in `lens` using distributive functors or the simpler

```
type Setter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
over :: Setter s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
```

As the identity type is both a functor and an applicative, it unifies with lenses and (I assume in your case) traversals.

Comment: A more specific question is, why does GHC not infer the context of the left hand side of the expression given constraints can be inferred from what is on the right hand?

Comment: I think inference is not the problem here; there is no way for `over (_all' 2)` to type-check since you have defined `over` too restrictively. There will never be a way for `forall f. Functor f => ...` to type-check with `Applicative f => ...`. It's not that GHC can't infer the right context; it's that you've asked it to infer something impossible.